# Underline abruptly appears and deletes the code. How can I prevent this?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Sometimes when I'm editing python code in Jupyter Notebook, an underline abruptly appears.

[image]

I'm trying to edit the code anyway, then the underlined code is deleted when I click it or try to make a selection of some part of the code with Shift button on the keyboard or dragging of the mouse. I tried Ctrl+A to select and copy the whole code but Ctrl+A deleted the whole code.

Actually I don't know what is happening. I don't know exactly how I created the underline or how I deleted the underlined code, hence, I cannot prevent it from happening.

I'm new to Python and Jupyter and trying to use it.
But this has already happened 3-4 times. Please help me.

Comment: Consider filing a bug report. Unless someone has encountered the bug before, we're not likely to be able to help.

Comment: Is it still possible to undo the deletion? Either from the edit menu or with control-z?

Comment: It does appear to start and end with a Chinese(?) character, so it may be a UTF code point issue. That won't help you, but it may make it more reproducible, by e.g. trying out with exactly those characters.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+Z to undo the deletion but it didn't work. The characters are Korean, actually. Thank you for your comments. Maybe this problem is not common.:(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today and I didn't know why, that's the reason I find this post.
However, I was able to recover with the following method:

1, hold the Crtl + z, not the single click, and the deleted content will be back.

2, once you got everything deleted back, save the notebook and reopen it.

Comment: To me, this issue happened in jupyter notebook.